# iOS7 how to add a UINavigationController to a nib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

Ok so I have a view controller with a button. When that button is pressed I have another view controller that will be presented modally. I would like to embed that view controller in a navigation controller, but this can't be done programmatically, the navigation controller needs to be in the xib.

In my xib I have two objects: the navigation controller, and a view object that has all of my view controllers content. The navigations controller's view controller has its view property set to my view object.

My issue is that in my parent view controller I am trying to present the modal with this code

```
self.modalController = modalController.new;
self.modalController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:self.modalController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

And then I get this crash:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <ParentController: 0xXXXXXXXX>.'
```

This just baffles me and I can't seem to figure out how to get passed it. I understand that this is achievable via programmatically setting up a navigation controller but I cannot use that route for this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: check some basic tutorial, its very basic. check this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)

Comment: `self.modalController = modalController.new;` - This syntax is invalid. It should be `self.modalController = [YourModalControllerClass new];`. I've also found the using a `UINavigationController` is easiest to do programmatically (or via Storyboards). Why do you *have* to use a xib?

Comment: Due to other set-up elements in my project im afraid it being in the xib is the only option currently. Its just frustrating because i know this works programmatically like you said.

Comment: In storyboard use storyboard Id to instantiateWithStoryboardId method.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to successfully instantiate any UIViewController class (or subclass) from a xib file. The only reason those object are there in Interface Builder is for use in Storyboards. You will have to figure out a way to do it in code. You can always create the UIView in a xib and then set the view of a view controller to the view loaded from a xib. There's a couple different ways to do that...

```
NSString *aNibName = @"customNibName";
MyViewController* myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:aNibName bundle:nil];
[navigationController pushViewController:myViewController];
```

Make sure to set File's Owner of the View created in Interface Builder to the UIViewController subclass.